# Server side validation of form

Tags: magento-1.9, validation

How to validate all form field

```
 if (!Zend_Validate::is($this->getRequest()->getPost('product[name]'), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $error = true;
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError(Mage::helper('example')->__('Please enter product name'));
        }

        if (!Zend_Validate::is($this->getRequest()->getPost('product[description]'), 'EmailAddress')) {
            $error = true;
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError(Mage::helper('example')->__('Please enter Email'));
        }
```

Using this code i am validate **NotEmpty** and **EmailAddress** but also i want to validate only number any other form validation so which class is use for all that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RTFM :-)

For numbers: `Zend_Validate_Digits` so `Zend_Validate::is($value, 'Digits')`

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.validate.set.html